# The URL provided by AWS to upload files endpoint result in Error: SignatureDoesNotMatch after accessing it

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to use [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/uploading-to-amazon-s3-directly-from-a-web-or-mobile-application/) tutorial to upload files directly from the browser in a bucket using presigned URL.
I tryed this:

```
export const myFunction = async (imageType: string) => {
  const s3 = new AWS.S3();
  const imageName = "somename";
  const s3Params = {
    Bucket: bucketname,
    Key: imageName,
    ContentType: 'image/' + imageType,
    Expires: 300,
  };
  const uploadURL = await s3.getSignedUrlPromise('putObject', s3Params);
  return JSON.stringify({
    uploadURL,
    imageName,
  });
};
```

And I do get back an URL in postman, I accessed it and then it redirected me to a new request, I set it to put and try to send the request without any file and with a file with the same name from the URL (the name of the image appear in the URL) in the form-data, sent it, but both my tries resulted in this error :

```
SignatureDoesNotMatch. The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.
```

I read something on stack, found oput it could be due to the file name if it has exotic characters, but it isn't my case.
How can I solve this problem?